# Submit event from few forms

Tags: jquery

I have a two or more forms on my page in a row.
I'm trying to hook submit event like:

```
$('form',someObj).submit(function(e){ 
   /* Do some stuff with ajax */ 
   return false; 
});
```

But always receive events only from a first (by code) form.

Also used each() function to bind event for each object, same thing..

What's wrong? 
Thanks!

Comment: Is your code wrapped in a document.ready call? something like `$(function() { });`?

Comment: of course, otherwise I wouldn't even receive events from the first form

Comment: One more thing, I'm looking in another object: $('form',someObj);

Comment: Are both forms within `someObj`? It sounds like your selector is not matching the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `someObj` contains both forms this will work, however if you just want to attach to the only two forms in the page, leave the context off the selector, like this:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){ 
 /* Do some stuff with ajax */ 
 return false; 
});
```

This will search for all forms in the document, alternatively, search for forms via a class or ID, like this:

```
$('form.ajaxy') //forms with class="ajaxy"
$('#form1, #form2') //forms with id="form1" and id="form2"
```